# Mint the royalty token with pycardano

Tags: nft, minting, metadata, policy, python

Good morning everyone,

I have a question regarding the royalty token. I've already read about this subject, and I understand that I need to mint a token with metadata like this:

```
{
    "777": {
        "rate": "0.1"
        "addr": [
            "addr1q8g3dv6ptkgsafh7k5muggrvfde2szzmc2mqkcxpxn7c63l9znc9e3xa82h",
            "pf39scc37tcu9ggy0l89gy2f9r2lf7husfvu8wh"
        ]
    } 
}
```

however I don't understand how can I associate this token to a policy id if it is not identified anywhere.

The normal metadata has it's policy id after the "721" identifier and before the properties of each token. But for this royalty token, only the "777" identifier is defined.

I wrote a code to mint NFTs following the example in pycardano repository, and it runs smoothly, but I don't know how to mint the royalty token using pycardano.

Can someone help me?

I hope you all have an awesome day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CIP27](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip27/):

> Process Flow
>
> 1. Create policy for planned assets.
> 2. Mint no name token with community standard royalties metadata.
> 3. Burn no name token to free up UTxO (recommended, but not required).
> 4. Mint planned assets using this same policy.

In the transaction you have to **mint a token of the intended policy ID, with empty asset name**. The policy is not referenced in the metadata.

Comment: yes, thank you a lot. what was being confused was the "no name token" part. Solved.